# costmap_2d: how to publish local costmap to topic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d, occupancy-grid, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running costmap_2d with PointCloud2 feed from a 3D lidar as the only source. Lidar points are preliminary filtered, the ground is mostly segmented out. It is used as a singular source for the singular plugin of type ObstacleLayer.

As I'm using the output occupancy grid for use with home-made custom code, I would like to have a small portion of costmap near the robot position be published after every update as OccupancyGrid. I guess this is what local_costmap settings can be used for, right?

Well, false. The setup works the same way with and without additional YAML file for the local costmap. Even worse, I cannot get the full costmap to be published every step. The /costmap/costmap topic is being published once at the start, all the rest time only costmap/costmap_update are published. This is happening despite always_send_full_costmap: true in the config.

What and where should I write to get instant local occupancy grid published?

Below are my two YAML files and the portion in the launchfile where I run the costmapping node. I'm working in Xubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic.

in the launchfile:

```
<node name="costmap_node" pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_node" output="screen" clear_params="true">
      <rosparam file="$(find lidar_proc)/params/costmap/costmap_common_voxel_params.yaml" command="load" ns="costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find lidar_proc)/params/costmap/local_costmap_quan_params.yaml" command="load" ns="costmap" />
          <remap from="/cloud_in" to="/lidar/flt_out_cloud"/>
    </node>
```

costmap_common_voxel_params.yaml:

```
transform_tolerance: 0.5,
robot_base_frame: base_link,

width: 200,
height: 200,
origin_x: -150,
origin_y: -50,

resolution: 0.2,
footprint:
- [-11.2, -3.2]
- [-11.2, 3.2]
- [0.2, 3.2]
- [0.2, -3.2],
update_frequency: 10.0,
static_map: false,
publish_frequency: 10.0,
max_obstacle_height:  3.0,
min_obstacle_height:  -2, 
obstacle_range: 70.0,
raytrace_range: 70.0,
always_send_full_costmap: true,

plugins:
    - {name: obstacles,          type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}

obstacles: {
  z_resolution: 0.2,
  z_voxels: 15,
  origin_z: -2.0,
  publish_voxel_map: true,
  mark_threshold: 0.5,
  enabled: true,
  max_obstacle_height:  3.0,
  min_obstacle_height:  -2,
  obstacle_range: 70.0,
  raytrace_range: 70.0,
  inflation_radius: 0.0,
  combination_method: 1,
  observation_sources: lidar_obstacles,
  lidar_obstacles: {
       sensor_frame: /Sensor,
       data_type: PointCloud2,
       topic: /cloud_in,
       expected_update_rate: 5.0,
       observation_persistence: 0.0,
       max_obstacle_height:  3.0,
       min_obstacle_height:  -2,
       marking: true,
       clearing: false,
       raytrace_range: 70.0,
       obstacle_range: 70.0}
  }
```

local_costmap_quan_params.yaml:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  resolution: 0.2
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  width: 20
  height: 20
  always_send_full_costmap: true,
  plugins:
    - {name: obstacles,      type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282059/costmap_2d:-how-to-publish-local-costmap-to-topic/) by [teonik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32020/teonik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is your root problem, but you have some problems with your params. Splitting the params into two files is mostly for people who use a global and local costmap. Since you're just using the costmap_node (which has only one costmap), you can just define one param file. The params in the second file are not loaded to the correct place, since they will be  loaded to `/costmap_node/costmap/local_costmap/global_frame` (for example) which is one too many namespaces.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0